# java: stream inside foreach - refactor

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying of finding ways to refactor my code to be more readable.
I have two lists:

```
List<Person> persons; //get from DB
List<PersonTemplate> personTemplates;//get from DB
List<Person> newList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I need to take specific items from the personTemplates-list and check if they exist in the persons list. If they don't, then I need to add the template personTemplate- item to the list: "newList", otherwise add the person-item to the "newList".

Here is my code:

```
//Get specific items from the template-list
List<Person> registeredPersons = personTemplates.stream
  .filter(person -> person.getProfile() == Enum.Registered) 
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

//Now iteration through the registeredPersons list and checking if they exist in the persons-list
registeredPersons.forEach(regPerson->
   persons.stream()
       .filter(p -> regPerson.getId().equals(p.getId())
       .filter(p -> regPerson.getProfileName().equals(p.getName())
       .findFirst()
       .map(newList::add)
       .orElseGet(() -> newList.add(templateToPersonMapper(regPerson)));
```

However it doesn't end here. 
I need to iterate over the persons list again, to filter other specific items and add them into the list. So my code becomes not readable anymore, I am having to much loops. 
Is it a good approach of having streams inside a forEach loop?

Comment: Do you think these logic can reside in the SQL query something similar like this?
SELECT * FROM PersonTemplate PT LEFT JOIN Person P ON PT.ID = P.ID AND PT.NAME = P.PROFILENAME WHERE P.PROFILE='Registered'

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions. An enum constant shoul be written in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you want to combine a big list with all the Person objects.

This is what I would do:

```java
// convert all the PersonTemplate to Set<Person>
Set<Person> registeredPersons = personTemplates.stream()
    .map(templateToPersonMapper(regPerson))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
// add all the person into this Set, if you override the equals/hashcode, it'll automatically remove the duplicates
registeredPersons.addAll(persons);
```

If overriding the `hashCode` or `equals` method is not an option, then always go with map:

```java
// build a Map key is id + ";" + name
Map<String, Person> registerdPersonMap = personTemplates.stream()
    .map(regPerson ->templateToPersonMapper(regPerson))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(regPerson -> regPerson.getId() + ";" + regPerson.getName(), regPerson -> regPerson));
 // build Map from Person in the same way, add to the above map       
Map<String, Person> personMap = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(person -> person.getId() + ";" + person.getName(), person -> person));

// add all
registerdPersonMap.putAll(personMap);
```

Correct me if I misunderstanding the question.
Hope it helps

Comment: So I have to override equals/hashcode so the two instances (Person and PersonTemplate) are considered as equals when they have the same attributes which is in my case the "id" and the "profileName" ? So I would need override equals/hashcode in the "Person-class"

Comment: Depends on what you want. If `id` and `profileName` is all you need, you need to override both the hashcode and equals with only the two fields.

Comment: I am not sure if I can override the equals/hashcode method on the person-object, since these are objects attached to the hibernate session and according to my understanding the contract of the equals() and hashCode() method when writing in to the DB is not the same as comparing templates with persons. I should mention that this id is the template-id (not the id used as primary key which is used by hibernate for equality, sry I should have mentioned that)

Comment: Ok, I think you can consider Map<Stirng, Person>, I'll update my answer